# What is the "natural" representation i.e. the formula $\pi(g,v)$ of SO(2) on $\Bbb C^2$ and why is it unitary?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

**What is the "natural" representation i.e. the formula $\pi(g,v)$? I just can't find anywhere a clear statement saying what it is**

The representation is supposed to be a map $\pi(g,v):G\times V \to V$ s.t $\pi (g)$ is linear for every $g\in G$.
Since these group is composed of rotations my guess is that $\pi(g) $ is the the linear map given by

$$\pi(g):V\to V: v\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
\cos \phi & - \sin \phi \\
\sin \phi & \cos \phi
\end{pmatrix}v
$$

But still what is the formula for the action $\pi(g,v)$?

Secondly, why is this representation unitary?